# Set 'Hyphens' to manual in CSS to prevent word breaks

Tags: css, wordpress

I've tried everything that I know and found online but I don't seem to be successful.

In some sections of my side the words get broken up.

As you can see in the picture my css splits the word "selectiebureau" this should stay 1 word.
[image]
 When I inspect my site I can see the following.

```
`body {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
}`
```

When I "turn-off" the "hypens:auto" than I get the result that I want.
But, when I remove the "hyphens: auto" in my CSS than I don't get the result anymore.

For your information, I cleared the cache of my site after I changed my CSS.

Any suggestions how I need to correct this in my CSS?

You can find the website on

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] - and read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Pete It doesn't seem that bad a question to me and from what I can gather the guy is Dutch, so English isn't going to be his first language.

Comment: @PhillHealey read the second link of my comment and now OP has removed the link from the question, you see why this question is rubbish in the grand scheme of this forum

Comment: @Pete I know we get lots of crap on here. I just think this isn't right down there with the crappest and maybe we need to give non native English speakers a bit of slack. But, I understand where you are coming. My general measure is if I can understand the question without much effort, then i'll try and answer but if I have to work to figure out the question they can forget it.

Comment: @PhillHealey this is meant to be a repository to help future visitors to the site, if you read the question in it's current format - with no link, no code and just an image, it is not useful at all.  Further more the English in this question is a lot better than most of the English people use on this site so I would say OP has a good grasp of it.  Once you have answered a few more questions (and started to get downvoted for answering questions like this) you will understand and stop doing it - I used to answer these types of questions too but you find it leads OP to being lazy in future

Comment: @PhillHealey, besides it's against the direct rules of the site -
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: @Pete, first of all thank you for the comment about my English. It isn't my first language as I'm Belgian. I try not to ask to many questions on this forum and always look at previous Questions and answers. But what it difficult in this case is for me to formulate my question. So please feel free to adjust my question so people with the same issue can use this in the future. Also, I'm not a specialist on these type of things, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you currently have this:

```
body {
hyphens: auto;
line-height: 1.5;
}
```

If you remove the hyphens line it removes the breaking up of words, that I think you are trying to remove. (Try without first).

If for some reason you are unable / unwilling to change the stylesheet, you will need to create a new css rule with the following:

```
body {
hyphens: manual !important;
}
```

Depending on how your css is loaded you may or may not need the '!important' directive to get this to work.

Alternatively you mentioned that you have a word-wrap css rule that you tried to change. You didn't use a correct value for the word-wrap rule. So try this instead:

```
word-wrap:normal;
```

Here's some info on the valid values for [word-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

Comment: when I go into "Inspect" on my browser and turn-off the "hypens" than it works. But when I put it in my css it doesn't work...

Comment: That is likely due to prioritisation of the css. Have you tried the '!important' directive with your rule? Also, remember that css can be cached, so maybe your browser isn't currently loading your new rule. Can you see your new rule via the inspector?

Comment: It seems I added content to my answer in the wrong place. Ive reordered it now, so things should be clearer.

Comment: No, I can't. Also when I use 'hyphens: manual' it doesn't work. 'manual' isn't an option.

Comment: What do you mean 'manual' isn't an option? You can just type css. Anyway, you could try one of the other options as explained in the link that I posted as part of my answer.

Comment: I know I can just type in css. I've added 'body {
hyphens: manual !important;
}' in my child css file but it doesn't work. I also tried the other options without luck. I start thinking that I do something wrong in my css file.

Comment: If I go to your site, it is working and I can see that the css rule is being used via Firebug. You are probably just seeing the old cached css. Try viewing your site in your browsers private mode.

Comment: I've just tried it in Google Chrome and it works. But in safari it doesn't. Do I need to change anything else to make it work in all browsers?

Comment: Found it. Need to use the following to make it work on Safari as wel. ' body {
    hyphens: manual !important;
    -webkit-hyphens: manual;
    -moz-hyphens: manual;
}'

Comment: You should always test in various browsers.

Comment: @WouterS Upvoting my comments sadly doesn't award me more points. ;-)